# Cloudpages rules for displaying smart capture form

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, subscriber, smart-capture

I'm looking for a way to build a rule inside of a cloudpage saying...if a subscriber filled out any smart capture form previously, then that subscriber will no longer see any forms/will not be required to submit contact information, on any cloudpages visited in the future. In other words, a way to prevent a contact from having to submit their information more than one time, if they are interested in accessing content from multiple pages. Is there a way to set up on the back end or through script in cloudpages?

Comment: How many different data extensions do you use with Smart Capture?

Comment: There are a handful of different data extensions used with smart capture

Answer (score 0):

If your users are accessing the page from a link in a Marketing Cloud email, you can place conditional AMPScript/SSJS around where your SmartCapture lives on the page. Edit the business logic to identify contacts that have already submitted the form. Accessing the form from such a link gives you access to the "Context", so variables/personalization strings like "_SubscriberKey" are available to you.

[image]

If the visitor is simply visiting the page with no context it all gets a lot more complicated. You could do some extensive customisation of the form to make some sort of AJAX call off to check the visitor's details using a custom CloudPages code resource. Secondly, you could potentially cookie the visitor using AMPScript or SSJS on successful form submission. This would not prevent further submissions from other devices owned by the visitor or where the visitor deletes or withholds cookies.